# Разбор массива

Tags: массивы, json, php

Здравствуйте. 
Что то мучался - мучался..=) Лучше спрошу у знатоков=) 
Есть вот такой массив.

```
{ "/live": { "name" : "XXXXXX", "listeners" : "1", "description" : "Dj XXXXXX", "title" : "Wolfmother - Vagabond", "genre" : "Various", "url" : "http://www.XXXXXX.ru" } }
```

Как правильно его разобрать? 
Чтобы данные выводить в echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разве это не json?

```
$new_array = json_decode($array);
```

где $array - исходный массив, а $new_array можно выводить через print_r();

Comment: json. 
Но по каким то причинам я не могу его разбить по ключам и выводить по тем самым ключам. =)

Comment: @RattleSneyk Поставь флаг TRUE
 

    $result_parse = json_decode($text, TRUE);


Таким образом функция json_decode переходит в режим массивов, а не объектов.

Comment: Точно!=) Спасибо большое.=)

Comment: и еще вопрос можно?=) 
Как вытащить мне в echo вот эту часть ( [/live] => Array (

Тоесть получить значение /live

Comment: @RattleSneyk 

    echo $new_array['live']['name']; // выведет XXXXXX

Comment: @RattleSneyk

    $key = key($new_array);

можно получить сразу все ключи

    array_keys($new_array);