# Разбор многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы, json, foreach

Есть скрипт, который выдает информацию в таком виде:

```
{

"status": "ok",
"ID": "",
"city": "Kiev",
"name": "Viktoriya",
"ads": [{
    "name_ads": "Запись 1",
    "url_ads": "Ссылка 1",
    }, {
    "name_ads": "Запись 2",
    "url_ads": "Ссылка 2",
}]
```

Не могу вывести (`echo`) все эти параметры вида:

```
"Запись 1 -  Ссылка 1; Запись 2 - Ссылка 2".
```

Comment: Начните с Json_decode

Comment: в итоге имею строку вида {"status":"ok","ID":"94176","city":"Kiev","name":" Viktoriya","ads":[{ и так далее...
Мне кажется так ее тяжелее будет приводить в echo

Comment: Похоже что тут, нужный вам ответ уже есть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719550/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-foreach?rq=1

Comment: Также взгляните на это решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/333116/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Я не очень понял, у вас это не получается?

```
<?php

$json = '{
"status": "ok",
"ID": "",
"city": "Kiev",
"name": "Viktoriya",
"ads": [
    {
      "name_ads": "Запись 1",
      "url_ads": "Ссылка 1"
      }, 
    {
      "name_ads": "Запись 2",
      "url_ads": "Ссылка 2"
    }
  ]
}';

$array = \json_decode($json, true);
$result = '';
foreach ($array as $name => $item) {
    if ($name === 'ads' && \is_array($item)) {
        foreach ($item as $key => $ads) {
            $keys = \array_keys($item);
            if ($key === \end($keys)) {
                $result .= $ads['name_ads'] . ' - ' . $ads['url_ads'];
            } else {
                $result .= $ads['name_ads'] . ' - ' . $ads['url_ads'] . '; ';
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Результат:

```
json.php:35:string 'Запись 1 - Ссылка 1; Запись 2 - Ссылка 2' (length=64)
```

Comment: не слишком ли много кода? чем не угодил сразу `foreach($array['ads'] ...`?

Comment: teran, не посчитайте наглым, приведите, пожалуйста, пример с foreach($array['ads']  на данном json.

Answer (score 0):

для конкретно данного результирующей строки можно применить, например, следующий код:

```
$txt = '{"status":"ok","ID":"","city":"Kiev","name":"Viktoriya","ads":[{"name_ads":"Запись 1","url_ads":"Ссылка 1"},{"name_ads":"Запись 2","url_ads":"Ссылка 2"}]}';
$json = json_decode($txt, true);

$result = implode('; ', array_map(function($v){
                             return $v['name_ads'].' - '.$v['url_ads'];
                          }, $json['ads']));

echo "\"{$result}\".";
```

отмечу, что у вас не совсем валидный json, есть пара лишних запятых.

вариант без `array_map`:

```
$result = [];
foreach($json['ads'] as $v){
    $result[] = $v['name_ads']." - ".$v['url_ads'];
}
$result = implode('; ', $result);
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! Будьте добры, подскажите, как добавить спереди информацию из блоков "ID", "city" и "name".

Comment: @Nickolay `echo $json["ID"].'-'.$json['city'].'-'.$json['name'];` ?

Comment: @Nickolay дополнил ответ

Comment: Уважаемые, прошу помощи. В массиве "ссылка" имеются ссылки (URL), которые заканчиваются на .html#dc12345678. Как обрезать все то, что идет после "html" (то есть #dc12345678). Пробовал substr с конца, но в массиве это не проходит.

Comment: решено. спасибо